# Datetimepicker doesn't function inside collapse panels

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

*********THIS WAS A MISTAKE- THE DATETIMEPICKER.JS WAS CORRUPTED* APOLOGIES.********

```
<div id="post" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <br />
            <br />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.datepicker1').datepicker();
            </script>
                <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
                    <input id="date_txt" runat="server" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" />
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The datepicker works fine everywhere else. Except when put inside a collapsible panel such as this.
Am I doing it wrong?

UPDATED CODE:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                 pickTime: false
             });
         });
    </script>
    <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append date">
        <input id="date_txt" runat="server" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" />
        <span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons, datepicker not working inside collapse panels

in HTML you have `id` selector

```
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
```

in script, you are targeting class

```
$('.datepicker1').datepicker();
```

should be

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker();
```

and you are missing closing braces `});` for ready event which causes syntax error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    }); <---This was missing
</script>
```

**Edit**

As you only want to show the date not time, I believe this `pickTime: false` not supported because `pickDate` and `pickTime` have been removed from current version.

So try like this and also you can set the date-format too which I think you are trying to set inside input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({
           format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
       });
    });
</script>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wte3yxef/1/)

Comment: I made the changes- the button appears to be clickable when hovered over, but on clicking it displays nothing. Refer to the updated question for changes.
Could it be the CSS?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. I tried and it still won't function. As I said, the datepicker works fine with panels that are static and non-collapsing. It's just the collapsing panels that doesn't seem to display the input calendar.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the body appending. It might be visible behind that collapsable panel for all I know.

Comment: ok let me check it will collapsed panels will update the answer

Comment: That fiddle works! And guess what happens when I copy the same code on my page- it doesn't! The button just doesn't respond.

Comment: check browser console log for errors, see what's there

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ Home.aspx:252` anonymous function? :O

Comment: then my friend, the code is fully working check this line `Home.aspx:252` what's there could be of many reasons, check JS libraries, change `$(function () {` to `$(document).ready(function() {` or may be the datetime script is above the JS libraries,

Comment: I debugged the errors. It still won't open. This is hilarious! The button just won't work.

Comment: why not put your code in the fiddle and see if it's working there? http://jsfiddle.net/wte3yxef/3/ put it here and update it, let me have look at it too

Comment: Damn corrupted min.js! I'm so sorry to drag you along all this. Thanks a lot!